# Cannot delete Product record after upgrading from Dynamics 365 CRM 8.1 to Dynamics 365 CRM 9

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, faultexception

I have tried the following steps in CRM 9:

1. Disabled all the plugins related to Product Entity
2. Created a new Product without any Parent or Child product.
3. Tried deleting the product. This step throws an error. The error I received was:

[image]

> SQL Server Error
>
> A SQL Server error occurred.
>
> Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 Community for solutions or contact your organization's
>   Microsoft Dynamics 365 Administrator. Finally, you can contact
>   Microsoft Support. If you contact support, please provide the
>   technical details.

Complete error:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Generic SQL error.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <OrganizationServiceFault
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ActivityId>1a6a5d86-5bf0-46ed-b3f8-dd8bff935329</ActivityId>
                    <ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorDetails
                        xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiExceptionSourceKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">Plugin/Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.CustomBusinessEntityService
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiOriginalExceptionKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Generic SQL error. ---&gt; Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Generic SQL error. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TrySetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean&amp; usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteWithRetry[TResult](Func`1 ExecuteMethod, IDbCommand command)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass105_0.&lt;InternalExecuteReader&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Nullable`1 commandBehavior, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Boolean impersonate, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;CollectForCascadeWrapper&gt;b__0(IDbCommand cmd)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;Collect&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.CollectForCascadeWrapper(IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 entityOtc, ExecutionContext context, Boolean UseIdentityColumnForOrdering)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.CollectForDelete(IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 entityOtc, ExecutionContext context)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8_0.&lt;CascadeDeleteDB&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass41_0.&lt;Delete&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass192_0.&lt;Delete&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context)
       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2_1.&lt;Execute&gt;b__0()
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiStepKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" i:type="b:guid">aecabb1b-ea3e-db11-86a7-000a3a5473e8
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiDepthKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:int">1
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiActivityIdKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" i:type="b:guid">1a6a5d86-5bf0-46ed-b3f8-dd8bff935329
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiPluginSolutionNameKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">System
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                        <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                            <a:key>ApiStepSolutionNameKey</a:key>
                            <a:value
                                xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">System
                            </a:value>
                        </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    </ErrorDetails>
                    <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
                    <Timestamp>2018-09-18T03:20:59.8142468Z</Timestamp>
                    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
                    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
                    <InnerFault>
                        <ActivityId>1a6a5d86-5bf0-46ed-b3f8-dd8bff935329</ActivityId>
                        <ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>
                        <ErrorDetails
                            xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                            <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
                            <Timestamp>2018-09-18T03:20:59.8152333Z</Timestamp>
                            <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
                            <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
                            <InnerFault>
                                <ActivityId>1a6a5d86-5bf0-46ed-b3f8-dd8bff935329</ActivityId>
                                <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
                                <ErrorDetails
                                    xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
                                    <Message>Exception output:: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TrySetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean&amp; usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteWithRetry[TResult](Func`1 ExecuteMethod, IDbCommand command)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass105_0.&lt;InternalExecuteReader&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Nullable`1 commandBehavior, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
       at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Boolean impersonate, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;CollectForCascadeWrapper&gt;b__0(IDbCommand cmd)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;Collect&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.CollectForCascadeWrapper(IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 entityOtc, ExecutionContext context, Boolean UseIdentityColumnForOrdering)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CrmCascadeDBHandler.CollectForDelete(IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 entityOtc, ExecutionContext context)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8_0.&lt;CascadeDeleteDB&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass41_0.&lt;Delete&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass192_0.&lt;Delete&gt;b__0()
       at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
    ClientConnectionId:7450d172-3354-4b86-a295-f34a0dffe915
    Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
    ClientConnectionId before routing:5020d858-2313-42e2-9225-9b0f9e42d91f
    Routing Destination:d74edb5d942c.tr26.westus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11158
    Error(s) details: 
    Class: 0x10
    LineNumber: 1
    Message: Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    Number: 208
    Procedure: 
    Server: d74edb5d942c.tr26.westus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11158
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
    State: 1
    ToString(): System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    --
    Class: 0x10
    LineNumber: 1
    Message: Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    Number: 208
    Procedure: 
    Server: d74edb5d942c.tr26.westus1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11158
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
    State: 1
    ToString(): System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid object name 'RecommendationCacheBase'.
    --
    : Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #E4A582C0</Message>
                                    <Timestamp>2018-09-18T03:20:59.8162336Z</Timestamp>
                                    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
                                    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
                                    <InnerFault i:nil="true"/>
                                    <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
                                    <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
                                </InnerFault>
                                <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
                                <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
                            </InnerFault>
                            <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
                            <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
                        </OrganizationServiceFault>
                    </detail>
                </s:Fault>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you raise a support ticket with Microsoft so they can investigate this issue.